# Deploy of Spring Boot app to Heroku using heroku-maven-plugin - crashed app

Tags: maven, heroku, spring-boot

I'm trying to deploy my Spring Boot app using [Heroku Maven Plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin).
The deploy finishes fine (`mvn heroku:deploy`). But when I check Heroku app logs (`heroku logs --tail`), I see it isn't finding the Main class:

```
2017-10-03T23:50:45.702415+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main`
2017-10-03T23:50:48.064526+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2017-10-03T23:50:48.068505+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2017-10-03T23:50:48.237240+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class Main
2017-10-03T23:50:48.314862+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-10-03T23:50:48.301181+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

I don't have any `Procfile` (rely on defaults). Heroku Maven Plugin configuration looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <processTypes>
            <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main</web>
        </processTypes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The Main class path is:

```
BASEPROJDIR/src/main/kotlin/com/virtualstand/ExplorerApplication.kt
```

Comment: `2017-10-04T08:32:57.264704+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not find or load main class ExplorerApplication`

Comment: it works!! thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the classpath to the main class is correct:-

```
<configuration>
    <processTypes>
        <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* com.virtualstand.ExplorerApplication</web>
    </processTypes>
</configuration>
```